# How to determine Seasonal periods in MSTS function?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality, trend

I am seeking assistance in analyzing whether there are any discernible trends, seasonality, or cycles present in the monthly data represented by the following figures:
[image: First time series]
[image: Second time series]

I would greatly appreciate it if you could let me know how to set `seasonal.periods` in this code (12 or 6):

```
train.ts.msts <- msts(train.ts.df,seasonal.periods=12)
```

Should I ignore it and let the model automatically determine the seasonal periods based on the data as follows?

```
model1 <- hw(train.ts, seasonal="additive")
```